# WinHTTP Open method is causing delay?

Tags: rest, delphi, firemonkey, winhttp, winhttprequest

I am using WinHTTP 5.1 in one of my Delphi FMX application which connects to REST servers in parallel.
There are lot of GET and POST which are called continuously by the client.
I have observed that after say 200-300 GET commands below method is becoming extremely slow:

```
WinHTTPRequest.Open(FURL, FDocument, True)
```

The credentials are set properly and i can observe on Wireshark that the Open method is taking approx a minute to execute as after open i am calling Send :

```
WinHTTPRequest.Send
```

Any advises ?